# Multiplayer Map blanking

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft 1.4.2, multiplayer, I get the following error: If I place a map in an item frame and use a new map, the old map in the item frame gets blanked, thus making it impossible to use multiple maps. Is there any bugfix for this?

[image: Map in frame]
[image: map in frame blanked]

Comment: Have you tried looking on the minecraft bug tracking site? They blogged about it recently: http://www.mojang.com/2012/10/introducing-the-minecraft-bug-tracker/. If the big isn't listed already, you could report it.

Comment: This is a bug. That has not been fixed. I have run into this problem running 1.6.1 single player. 

Only work around is reloading the world. (Save and quit, then restarting.) Not sure if that is any help for your multiplayer issues.

Comment: its pretty old the 1.4.2 minecraft version, and there is a lot of bugs about item frames, so i think if 1.5.2+ there is not this kind of bug. try it in another versions and say to me later.
maybe the bug is in the server.

Answer (score 1):

No, for that version, the newer version have that bugfix in the multiplayer (Bukkit framework), so i'd suggest going for a new version, or upgrading the server to the Bukkit framework, if it is your server.

Answer (score -1):

You are not able to use many many maps at once. This will prevent maps from being shown you have not gone to places you have been.So placing different maps means you show different places. Or I think this is my opinion.